# JavaScript Functions Not Working After AJAX XML HttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, svg, tooltip, zooming

I am creating an interactive map that allows the user to select year from timeline and filter events, this is done via XML HttpRequest that redraws the SVG everytime.

The SVG code for the map, including the JavaScript functions to zoom and the tooltip are re written everytime the user selects the year/filter. The code is a string in Java as it relies on if statements. However, whenever the user selects the year/filter the JavaScript functions do not work. The JavaScript code is repeated three times in the one class in separate if statements

This is the XML http Request code:

```
var year_selected = document.getElementById('year').innerHTML;                      
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "/BCMapYear.html/"+year_selected, true);
xhttp.send();
```

JavaScript:

```
"<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
                                        "var transformMatrix = [1,0,0,1,0,0];"+
                                        "var svg = document.getElementById('svg-map');"+
                                        "var viewBox = svg.getAttributeNS(null, \"viewBox\").split(\" \");"+
                                        "var centerX = parseFloat(viewBox[2])/2;"+
                                        "var centerY = parseFloat(viewBox[3])/2;"+
                                        "var matrixGroup = svg.getElementById(\"matrix-group\");"+
                                        "var origMatrix = [1,0,0,1,0,0];"+

                                        "function reset() {\n" + 
                                        "               for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {\n" + 
                                        "                   transformMatrix[i] = origMatrix[i];\n" + 
                                        "               }               \n" + 
                                        "               var newMatrix = \"matrix(\"+ transformMatrix.join(' ') + \")\";\n" + 
                                        "               matrixGroup.setAttributeNS(null, \"transform\", newMatrix); \n" + 
                                        "          \n" + 
                                        "           };"+

                                        "function pan(dx, dy) {"+
                                            "transformMatrix[4] += dx;"+
                                            "transformMatrix[5] += dy;"+

                                            "var newMatrix = \"matrix(\"+ transformMatrix.join(' ') + \")\";"+
                                            "matrixGroup.setAttributeNS(null, \"transform\", newMatrix);"+
                                        "}"+

                                        "function zoom(scale) {"+
                                            "for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {"+
                                                "transformMatrix[i] *= scale;"+
                                            "}"+

                                            "transformMatrix[4] += (1-scale) * centerX;"+
                                            "transformMatrix[5] += (1-scale)* centerY;"+

                                            "var newMatrix = \"matrix(\"+ transformMatrix.join(' ') + \")\";"+
                                            "matrixGroup.setAttributeNS(null, \"transform\", newMatrix);"+ 
                                        "}"+



                             "</script>"

                             +"<script type=\"text/ecmascript\">\n" + 
                                            "       (function() {\n" + 
                                            "        var svg = document.getElementById('svg-map');\n" + 
                                            "        var tooltip = svg.getElementById('tooltip');\n" + 
                                            "        var tooltipText0 = document.getElementById('tooltiptext0').firstChild;\n" + 
                                            "        var tooltipText1 = document.getElementById('tooltiptext1').firstChild;\n" + 
                                            "        var tooltipText2 = document.getElementById('tooltiptext2').firstChild;\n" + 
                                            "        var tooltipText3 = document.getElementById('tooltiptext3').firstChild;\n" + 
                                            "        var triggers = svg.getElementsByClassName('tooltip-trigger');\n" + 
                                            "        for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {\n" + 
                                            "            triggers[i].addEventListener('mousemove', showTooltip);\n" + 
                                            "            triggers[i].addEventListener('mouseout', hideTooltip);\n" + 
                                            "        }\n" + 
                                            "        function showTooltip(evt) {\n" + 
                                            "            var CTM = svg.getScreenCTM();\n" + 
                                            "            var x = (evt.clientX - CTM.e + 6) / CTM.a;\n" + 
                                            "            var y = (evt.clientY - CTM.f + 20) / CTM.d;\n" + 
                                            "            tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, \"transform\", \"translate(\" + x + \" \" + y + \")\");\n" + 
                                            "            tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, \"visibility\", \"visible\");\n" +
                                            "            tooltipText0.data = evt.target.getAttributeNS(null, \"data-tooltip-text0\");\n" + 
                                            "            tooltipText1.data = evt.target.getAttributeNS(null, \"data-tooltip-text1\");\n" + 
                                            "            tooltipText2.data = 
   evt.target.getAttributeNS(null, \"data-tooltip-text2\");\n" + 
                                            "            tooltipText3.data = 
    evt.target.getAttributeNS(null, \"data-tooltip-text3\");\n" + 
                                            "        }\n" + 
                                            "        function hideTooltip(evt) {\n" + 
                                            "            
    tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, \"visibility\", \"hidden\");\n" + 
                                            "        }\n" + 
                                            "    })()" + 
                                            "    </script>";
```

On the Console it comes up uncaught referenceerror zoom is not defined

Comment: You might need to post more code. What is 'zoom'?

Comment: edited to include javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can add (); after your block that you want executed.

```
(function(){
    //Bunch of code...
})();
```